# Transforma java a javascript

Tags: javascript, java, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando convertir java a js pero no se mucho de js, y pues estoy intentando convertir el principio de substitución de liskov [de esta pagina](https://enmilocalfunciona.io/principios-solid/)

**Este es el codigo a convertir**

```
public static void imprimirNumAsientos(Coche[] arrayCoches){  
        for (Coche coche : arrayCoches) {
            System.out.println(coche.numAsientos());
        }
    }

imprimirNumAsientos(arrayCoches);

abstract class Coche {

    // ...
    abstract int numAsientos();
}
class Renault extends Coche {

    // ...
    @Override
    int numAsientos() {
        return 5;
```

Comment: No tengo muy claro como hacerlo tal vez [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) te pueda servir

Comment: Quisiera aportar, pero primero me gustaría saber si tu objetivo detrás de la conversión es solamente aprender o si aspiras a algo más concreto como por ejemplo integrar Java y Javascript, usar cosas de Java en javascript, o cosas de Javascript en Java o toda esa variedad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten invito a leer la documentación acerca de [Clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes) en JavaScript.

> Las clases de javascript, introducidas en ECMAScript 2015, son una mejora sintáctica sobre la herencia basada en prototipos de JavaScript.

Por lo que la sintaxis del siguiente ejemplo solo puede ser utilizada a partir de ECMAScript 2015.

```js
/**
 * Abstract Class Coche.
 *
 * @class Coche
 */
class Coche {
  constructor(asientos) {
    this.asientos = asientos;
    if (this.constructor == Coche) {
      throw new Error("Abstract classes can't be instantiated.");
    }
  }
 
  numAsientos() {
    throw new Error("Method 'numAsientos()' must be implemented.");
  }
}

/**
 * Renault.
 *
 * @class Renault
 * @extends {Coche}
 */
class Renault extends Coche {
  constructor(asientos) {
    super(asientos);
  }
  numAsientos() {
    return this.asientos;
  }
}

/**
 * Ferrari.
 *
 * @class Ferrari
 * @extends {Coche}
 */
class Ferrari extends Coche {
  constructor(asientos) {
    super(asientos);
  }
  numAsientos() {
    return this.asientos;
  }
}

/**
 * Toyota.
 *
 * @class Toyota
 * @extends {Coche}
 */
class Toyota extends Coche {
  constructor(numAsientos) {
    super(numAsientos);
  }
  numAsientos() {
    return this.asientos;
  }
}
        
function imprimirNumAsientos(arrayCoches){  
  for (const coche of arrayCoches) {
    console.log(coche.numAsientos());
  }
}

const renault = new Renault(5);
const ferrari = new Ferrari(2);
const toyota = new Toyota(3);

imprimirNumAsientos([renault, ferrari, toyota]);
```

### Definiendo Clases

> Las clases son "funciones especiales", como las expresiones de funciones y declaraciones de funciones, la sintaxis de una clase tiene dos componentes: expresiones de clases y declaraciones de clases.

Debido a que las las clases no son más que funciones (hablando de JavaScript), entonces es posible implementar clases sin necesidad de ECMAScript 2015, utlizando funciones y prototipos.

```javascript
function Heroe(nombre, nivel) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.nivel = nivel;
}

Heroe.prototype.saludar = function() {
    return `${this.nombre} dice hola!`;
}
```

Lo anterior sería lo mismo que:

```javascript
class Heroe {
  constructor(nombre, nivel) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.nivel = nivel;
  }

  saludar() {
    return `${this.nombre} dice hola!`;
  }
}
```

Puedes encontrar más detalles [aquí](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript).

### TypeScript

Otra forma de tener clases (y otras muchas ventajas) es utilizando [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), lo cual ya es más parecido a utilizar lenguajes que sí están enfocados a POO, como lo son Java o C#.

```js
class Heroe {
  nombre: string;

  constructor(nombre: string) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  saludar() {
    return `${this.nombre} dice hola!`;
  }
}
```

Comment: les recuerdo que uno de los fuertes de JavaScript es que su implementación puede ser classless..

Comment: Les recuerdo que uno de los fuertes de ECMAScript 2015 son las clases :trollface: